# Network path to make absolute path - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, relative-path, absolute-path

I have some files in the network path (\machine\folder\folder..). In asp.net, trying to pull the files from this path. here i want to use relative path not this network(absolute) path. please suggest on how to?

Comment: What files are you trying to pull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Path.GetFullPath` should give you the relative path.

Alternatively,  if you are trying to link to images; for example, on a network share you would need to make sure that the share is visible to your web server.  You could then add specific AppSettings in your web.config to hold the UNC path to the Image directory:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="imagePath" value="\\server\images\" />
</appSettings>
```

In you code behind, you could then do something like this to get the image:

```
string img = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imagePath"].ToString() + "\\Image1.jpg";
```

Comment: @Yogesh I think the above answer should give you what you want.  Does this not work for you?